# proof of the open mapping theorem

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I have a question about the proof of the following theorem.

[image]

[image]

First, why is $Y \subset \cup n\bar{L}$ because $y \in ||x||L$?
Finally, I see that $p+y \in \bar{L}$, but why must $y-p$ also be $\in \bar{L}$ and so $y=1/2{p+y+y-p}\in \bar{L}$? Here, $\bar{L}$ may not be a subspace, actually I don't think it is a subspace since $L$ isn't. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can explain these to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every $y\in Y$ is contained in a set $||x||L$ where the $x$ depends on the $y$. So just pick an integer $n$ that is bigger than $||x||$. Then, since $||x||L\subset n||L||$, we can see that $y\subset nL$ for some $n$ that depends on $y$. Since every $y\in Y$ fits in such an $nL$, $$Y\subset \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty nL.$$

Secondly, since $y\in B_{0,Y}(t)$, so is $-y$. Thus, $p-y\in p+B_{0,Y}(t)\subset \overline L.$ Thus $y-p$ is an element of $\overline L$ too because if you can find a sequence $y_n\in L$ converging to $p-y$, then $-y_n$ converges to $y-p$.

That last part is using convexity of $\overline L$. As the closure of the linear image of a convex set (namely the unit ball in $X$), $\overline L$ is convex too. So the convex combination of elements $p+y$ and $y-p$ is in $L$ too.

Comment: $T\in B(X,Y)$ means $T$ is a linear map ??? in that case $0$ is clearly in $L$ so $p = 0$

Comment: The space $B(X,Y)$ is all bounded linear operators. If you see the proof, you'll notice that we just get the existence of $p$. We dont get to pick what it is.

Comment: @ Jake : $p$ is dummy as we know since the beginning it is $0$, this is enough for proving that this proof is "not good".

Comment: Knowing that 0 is in L is not enough to guarantee that a ball around 0 is also in L..